# Execute Expression OnShow in MDriven Turnkey

Tags: mdriven

I want to initialize some variables and do a search in a viewModel so in "Execute Expression On Show" I put :

```
vSeekParam := 'Check';
selfVM.Search
```

In the action that brings the Seeker ViewModel.

When prototyping in WECPOF, it changes the vSeekParam variable, but not when I run the model in Turnkey.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bringing up views is an asynchronous process - possibly the call to search is to early in OnShow - but if it is - it is undocumented.

Workaround: Add a ViewModel Column IsAction=true and make it periodic by setting the periodicity. In this action you can perform the selfVM.Search.

This is described in this wiki article: https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/QR-Code_to_drive_a_workflow_in_any_MDriven_turnkey_app